# How does STL algorithm work independent of Iterator type?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

How does STL algorithm work independent of Iterator type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Really, they just work. They use some pretty basic properties of templates, sometimes called static polymorphism. If you're familiar with the term, it is essentially a form of ducktyping. (If it looks like a duck, and it quacks like a duck, it must be a duck)

The trick is simple. Here's a very simple example:

```
template <typename T>
void say_hello(const T& t) {
  t.hello();
}
```

The `say_hello` function doesn't care which type its argument is. It doesn't have to derive from an interface or make any other kind of "promises" about what it is. All that matters is that the type *works* in this context. All we do with the type is call its `hello` function. Which means that this code will compile for any type that has a `hello` member function.

The STL algorithms work similarly. Here's a simple implementation of `std::for_each`:

```
template <typename iter_type, typename func_type>
void for_each(iter_type first, iter_type last, func_type f){
  for (iter_type cur = first; cur != last; ++cur) {
    f(*cur);
  }
}
```

This code will compile whenever the template types live up to the requirements placed on them; `iter_type` must have the pre-increment ++-operator. It must have a copy constructor, and it must have the != operator, and it must have the *-dereference-operator.

`func_type` must implement the function-call operator, taking an argument of the same type as you get by dereferencing an object of type `iter_type`. If I call `for_each` with types that satisfy these requirements, the code will compile. `iter_type` can be any type that satisifies these requirements. There is nothing in the code that says "this shall work with vector iterators and list iterators and map iterators". But as long as vector, list or map iterators implement the operators we use, it'll work.

Comment: You mean ++-increment operator?

Comment: doh. Actually I meant to write pre-increment. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 4):

STL algorithm are template functions, which means they can be called with any type.

When calling the function with a specific type, the compiler will try to compile an instance of the function for this specific type and report any compilation error (missing methods, type check errors, etc.)

For STL algorithms, as long as the type used behaves like an iterator (supports ++, dereferencing), it will work. That's why those algorithms works with native pointers too, because they support the same type of operations than iterators (that is how they were designed in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Is every iterator is derived from a common interface?

Comment: no, it doesn't use inheritance, or what is "usually" called polymorphism. Templates allow what it sometimes called "static polymorphism", which is what the STL relies on. But it has nothing to do with inheritance, interfaces or virtual functions.

Comment: This answer is correct. The downvoter ought to retract their vote, because they need to read a bit more.

Comment: Let's call it *Duck typing* + *generic specialization*

Answer (score 3):

Any STL algorithm is generated automatically by compiler for each iterator type you use it with.

It is called C++ templates or static polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Every STL algorithm is a template function which takes iterator type as its template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not all STL container/iterator algorithms have this independence. The ones that do are call Generic Algorithms, but these are usually just called STL algorithms.

With iterators only you can:

- inspect the sequence so you can do things like find, count, for_each,…
- change the value of the iterator references so you can do things like transform, copy, rotate, swap, replace, …
- reorder the values of the iterators, so you can do things like sort, merger, nth_element.

Some  non-generic algorithms can be broken up into 2 stages, a STL Generic  part and a container dependent part.  So in order to destroy all values that are greater than  7 in a vector we can do a remove_if  ( the generic part which only sorts the elements) followed by a  erase ( the non-generic part that destroys the value).